# Simulating keyboard tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

Is there a way to programmatically tap a key, just as a user would so the key pop up animation takes place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but a good amount of work.  It depends what your goal is.

[`UISpec`](http://code.google.com/p/uispec/) is a good place to start looking.  If you are interested in simulating clicks for testing purposes, then you can just use the library.  Otherwise, it would contain the source and pointers to how you can do it yourself.